# PHPMailer e foreach

Tags: php, phpmailer

Eu refiz o e-mail do meu site.

Dentre as novidades, agora pode-se enviar uma mensagem para mais de um e=mail.

Tenho esse select que busca quais e-mails serão dos destinatários:

```
<?php
/****** E-mails dos destinatários ******/
$sql_email_dest = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT email FROM tb_email_home_email WHERE id_item = '1'") or die(mysqli_error($config));

if(@mysqli_num_rows($sql_email_dest) <= '0'){
    echo "";
}else{
    while($r_sql_email_dest = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_email_dest)){
        $email_email_home_sel[] = $r_sql_email_dest[0];
    }
}   
/****** E-mails dos destinatários ******/   

?>
```

E no PHPMailer, este foreach para enviar:

```
<?php
foreach($email_email_home_sel as $email_contato){
    $mail->AddAddress($email_contato);            // E-mail do destinatário
}   
?>
```

É simples, mas tentei de várias formas...

Se eu colocar da forma antiga, com um e-mail (sem estar no foreach) funciona.

Mas da forma acima, sem chance.

Alguém já viu algum caso parecido?

Tem alguma idéia?

Comment: Olá Rogério Pancini, rodei seu script no meu servidor e funcionou direitinho. Na tabela coloquei 4 emails e recebi nos 4. O erro pode estar em outra parte do código. Se puder edite a pergunta acrescentando a parte do phpmailer

Comment: O erro pode estar nos emails salvos na base de dados, como caracteres especiais. Verifique se os emails estão cadastrados corretamente.